# Static image header in Panorama Control on Windows Phone

Tags: windows-phone, panorama-control

I would like to add an image as the header for a Panorama page and make it static so that it does not scroll as the user navigates between different Panorama Items. How can this be accomplished?

Answer (score 4):

I accomplished this by putting an image on top of the panorama. Basically I made the panorama header empty and placed a static image where the panorama header is supposed to be. This way when the user scrolls between different pages of the panorama, the image on top does not pan/scroll.